# useEffect update state only after first props changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have stateless component:

```
const Comp = memo(({ name, defaultExpanded }) => {
 const [ isExpanded, setExpand ] = useState(defaultExpanded)

 useEffect(() => {
    setExpand(defaultExpanded)
  }, [defaultExpanded])

 ...
})
```

And when I mount component with `defaultExpand = true` and then changing it to `false` it's work fine, but when I change it back to `true` it's now working. What I did wrong, and how can I properly synchronize props with state via useState/useEffect?

UPD: Link for code https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-taussig-xe2ck?fontsize=14

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo here? `defaultExpand` (prop) !== `defaultExpanded` (value you use)

Comment: @Andres sorry, there was a typo in question, but not in real code

Comment: Your code works [just fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-tdd-nxggo?fontsize=14) Problem probably lies on how you're toggling `defaultExpanded`

Comment: I've copied your component and use it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-frog-gutq8?fontsize=14) with fixed typo, everything works fine.

Comment: @Dupocas i'm toggle it via knobs in Storybook